# How can I change the data permissions to enable Graph Explorer on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-graph-search

Today, I was trying to see what Graph Explorer is.  I wasn't able to change the permission for my data and friends data.

My User Data permissions and Friends Data Permissions settings are enabled by default and I read that "basic permissions are enabled by default", but I saw a tutorial on YouTube where the user's permissions were all cleared.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The second question is outside of our scope here, so you'll have to find that information on one of the more theory-oriented SE sites.

Comment: Theory oriented, I was talking about facebook graph explorer!! and
I was just trying things and then I just turned off facebook paltfrom and then after re-enabling it, all the permissions were flushed ...!!

Comment: Yes, you're asking about graph theory in general, which, while a fascinating topic, is not on-topic here.

Comment: Facebook graph explorer is web application right ??

Comment: Yes, Facebook Graph Explorer is definitely on-topic here.  I was referring to the `Nice source to understand the social graph made by facebook, with nodes and edges.` portion of your question.

Comment: oops ...sorry ..! 
thank you ..>!
Where should I head too inorder understand it, if you any idea about it??
 I'm new SE...

Comment: The computer science [site](http://cs.stackexchange.com) is probably your best bet.  They have a `graph-theory` [tag](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory).  Go through some of the questions to see if they have already answered what you are after, and, if not, ask something specific, not just for a book recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

OP seems to have found a solution:

> [I just turned off facebook paltfrom and then after re-enabling it, all the permissions were flushed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57573/how-can-i-change-the-data-permissions-to-enable-graph-explorer-on-facebook#comment45900_57573)